# NullPointerException when launching web start app

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jnlp, java-web-start

After finally solving the jar signing problem (thank you everyone for your help!), a new one has now come up.

When trying to launch the web start app from the launch.jnlp file I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I use the jnlp file that points to the jar file on my computer, the app runs fine, but if I try to use the jar file in the website - I get the above error.

What exactly is the problem?

The jnlp file has the right format, otherwise why would it work on my local jar file?

Here is the jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>ExcelReader</title>
        <vendor>Adam</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.appquad.com"/>
        <description>ExcelReader</description>
        <description kind="short">ExcelReader</description>


    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
    <update check="background"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
       <j2se version="1.7+"/>
       <jar href="http://www.appquad.com/ExcelCopyApp/sExcelReader.jar" main="true"/>
       <jar href="http://www.appquad.com/ExcelCopyApp/lib/jxl.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <application-desc main-class="excelreader.ExcelCopyApp">

     </application-desc>
    </jnlp>
```

Comment: Is this the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's all it gives me.

Comment: Looks like WebStart can't locate your main class. You should have a line in your JNLP file saying something like `<jar href="yourjar.jar" main="true"/>`. What does that line say?

Comment: Why is the app. 1.7+ - what 1.7 functionality does it use?  Does the same exception occur if the `security` element is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that your JNLP file has the right format: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html

Comment: If it didn't have the right format, why would it have worked on my local jar file?

Comment: I looked at Mi Mee's link and in it it says to add the codebase and href to the jnlp tag. That solved the problem. I thought these attributes were no longer needed... weird. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: For validation of the JNLP, see also the last of the links in the [JWS info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (the link to JaNeLA).  And since Mi Mee's pointer to the spec. tipped you off about the codebase/href, it would make sense to mark it as 'correct'.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue. I was getting below exception while trying to launch
app through jnlp:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javaws.JnlpxArgs.execProgram(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.relaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source).
```

I have jdk 1.7 on my machine and any how some jar in JRE lib was missing or corrupted. I have resinstalled the JRE and it worked for me. I would suggest to figure out jar that is not getting picked up from jnlp file and relplace them and see if it works.